# Connected to 2 monitors but one is blurry

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

**EDIT :**
Monitor 1 resolution-2560 x 1440 (recommended) 
Monitor 2 resolution: 2048 x 1080 (there is no recommended resolution and the same resolution option as monitor 1 is not available)
Laptop resolution: 1920 x 1080 (recommended) 
Laptop details in attachment. 
I am using a DELL docking port with a lightning USB, reg type: K20A001

Connected my DELL laptop to TWO DELL monitors. They are the exact same monitors. One monitor has the Display settings option as 125% recommended whereas the other has 100% recommended and does not have the 125% option. My monitors have been replaced recently and this issue was not found in my previous monitors or my monitors at home.

**ISSUE ->** The monitor with 100% recommended display setting is blurry and flickers. The task bar is not displayed in full and the time on the extreme right is cut. 
IT guy worked on my laptop for two whole days and found nothing. He even replaced the faulty monitor to a brand new one and NOTHING. He thought I might have run out of RAM space and tried to insert extra space, but that did not help. 
He went over all sorts of combinations in the display settings for each monitor and nothing. I used my colleague's laptop to connect to the monitors and it is clear, no issues.

Is the problem with my laptop then?

Can someone please help in this matter? Thanks!

Comment: What resolutions are all the screens at? What sort of connectors are you using? Could you [edit] the question to include the make and model of laptop, this might be an issue with the graphics card.

Comment: @Burgi, I have made the necessary edits.

Comment: What is your laptop model? If it has only HBR2 then that is your issue. Not enough bandwidth. Check out the manual for your dock at page 17: https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/e/a/c/6/426f187fc65b141bb81fe34e2f2a7397b966.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with the lack of bandwidth in most 2019 and earlier laptops. The Display Port (USB-C) connection is only through the onboard Intel graphics, and uses HBR2, which has a max bandwidth of 8.6gbps. Per the table on the [WD19 docking station user manual](https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/e/a/c/6/426f187fc65b141bb81fe34e2f2a7397b966.pdf), at page 17, the minimum bandwidth for a single 1440p monitor is 5.2gbps. So two 1440p monitors use at least 10.4gbps of bandwidth, which is over capacity for HBR2.

I suggest you try using the WD19 for one monitor, and the HDMI on the laptop for the other monitor if it has it. Yes...it's more cables, but this is the only way I see to use two 1440p monitors with this setup. It'll also help file transfers since the USB-C connection wont be limited in bandwidth.

Comment: I connected 1 monitor through HDMI and it worked!! Thank you so so much.  In order to minimize the number of cables, is my only option a new laptop?

Comment: Glad I could help! Sadly only a new laptop can use a single USB-C cable for two QHD and higher monitors. And even then: make sure it does have expanded USB-C capabilities. I've only seen the Surface Laptop 3 with that enabled.