# would like a docking station supporting 3840 and 1920 in addition to laptop built-in display

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, docking-station

I have an HP Elitebook 650 G5, a Samsung J32J59 UHD monitor, and an HP 27es HD monitor. I am on MS Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362. I would like to connect the two displays (and power and a USB hub and a headphone-jack sound system) to a docking station. HP doesn't make one specifically for this model, and sold me an HP USB-C G5 docking station.

But if I connect both monitors, the available resolution on the UHD (in Windows Display Settings) drops to 1920. I normally connect it with a DisplayPort cable, and the HD monitor with HDMI; I've tried connecting the UHD with a USB-C to HDMI adapter, as well as connecting it with a regular HDMI-HDMI cable, but neither of those help.

I did connect both monitors, using DisplayPort and HDMI, directly to the PC -- that DOES work, indicating that the Intel 620 HD graphics chip in the laptop does support both (or all three if you count the built-in) displays.

I've spent some time on the phone with HP support (and Samsung, but they just confirmed things for me); they shipped me another docking station, but the results are the same.

I'm looking for other suggestions on this docking station, or suggestions about other docking stations that would support the rest of the hardware.

Comment: Your computer does not have a single port capable of driving a UHD monitor and a FHD monitor together. Refer to my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1520553/connected-to-2-monitors-but-one-is-blurry/1520865#comment2304043_1520865

Comment: OK, so it's not really the docking station that's the problem, but the hardware to which the USB-C port on the laptop that is incapable of driving both monitors at the resolutions that I wanted -- is that right?

Comment: Yes. The laptop's single USB-C itself isn't capable of the 8+gbps needed to drive the two monitors in DP mode.

Comment: So a different machine would be able to do that? Where do I find specs on the throughput of the USB-C ports on laptop?